# Startup script for gnome-terminal doesn't change tab title nor executes commands

Tags: gnome, manjaro, gnome-terminal

I'd like to automate the setup of my dev environment. I had to fallback from guake to gnome-terminal since guake (dropdown behavior was incredible) has issues with Wayland. I'm on Manjaro with gnome desktop.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --tab -t "TSR VIM" --working-directory /my/working/dir/ -- vim
gnome-terminal --tab -t "TSR CMD" --working-directory /my/working/dir/ -e 'git status'
gnome-terminal --tab -t "TSR Server" --working-directory /my/working/dir/ -e 'bundle exec hanami server'
```

This does the following:

1. command: works in full. A new tab is opened, title renamed and vim is started.
2. command: it runs git status but it stays in that state. I can't run any other commands after that. Also, the title is not renamed. The working directory is set.
3. command: same as the second. If I stop the server with CRTL + C, I cant use the tab anymore.

I'm also prompted to change **-e** to **--** for the 2. and 3. command. However, doing that returns another error: Failed to execve: File or directory with that name doesn't exist.

Finally, the initial tab remains opened.

I checked other SO questions and tried my google fu and implementing different solutions, however, I had no success.

<<<EDIT1

As per comment I tried:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t "TSR VIM" --working-directory /my/dir/ -- vim
gnome-terminal --tab -t "TSR CMD" --working-directory /my/dir/ -- bash -c 'git status'
gnome-terminal --tab -t "TSR Server" --working-directory /my/dir/ -- bash -c 'bundle exec hanami server'
```

Nothing changes with regards to the issues.

<<<EDIT1

Can someone help with this problem?

Best, seba

Comment: Does this answer your question?  
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/731261/gnome-terminal-how-to-send-commands/731266#731266

Comment: @WhiteOwl no, see my attempt above. I still have the same issues.

Comment: Adding `exec bash` seems to work well, e.g. `gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'git status; exec bash'`.

Comment: Adding `exec bash` solves the problem of being able to use the additional tabs, for example if stop the server. However, the initial tab remains opened and the CMD and Server tabs are not renamed.